# POST request fails with large data send to model deployed on Azure Container

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

**Summary**

I have a PyTorch model deployed on an Azure Container instance via the Azure Machine Learning Service SDK. The model takes (large) images for classification in standard numpy formatting.

It seems, I'm hitting a HTTP request size limit on the server side. Requests to the model succeeds with PNG images of a size in the 8-9mb range and fails with images of the 15mb+ size. Specifically, it fails with 413 Request Entity Too Large.

I assume, the limit is set in Nginx in the Docker image being build, as part of the deployment process. My question: *Given that the issue is due to the HTTP request size limit, is there any way to increase this limit in the azureml API?*

**Deployment process**

The deployment process succeeds as expected.

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig, Model
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice, Webservice
from azureml.exceptions import WebserviceException
from pathlib import Path

PATH = Path('/data/home/azureuser/my_project')

ws = Workspace.from_config()
model = ws.models['my_pytorch_model']

inference_config = InferenceConfig(source_directory=PATH/'src',
                                   runtime='python',
                                   entry_script='deployment/scoring/scoring.py',
                                   conda_file='deployment/environment/env.yml')

deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=2, memory_gb=4)
aci_service_name = 'azure-model'

try:
    service = Webservice(ws, name=aci_service_name)
    if service:
        service.delete()
except WebserviceException as e:
    print()

service = Model.deploy(ws, aci_service_name, [model], inference_config, deployment_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(True)
print(service.state)
```

**Testing via `requests`**

A simple test using requests:

```py
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import requests
from PIL import Image as PilImage

test_data = np.array(PilImage.open(PATH/'src/deployment/test/test_image.png')).tolist()
test_sample = json.dumps({'raw_data': 
    test_data
})
test_sample_encoded = bytes(test_sample, encoding='utf8')

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.post(
    service.scoring_uri,
    data=test_sample_encoded,
    headers=headers,
    verify=True,
    timeout=10
)
```

Produces the following error in `requests` for larger files:

```py
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

Which I guess is a known error in requests, when a connection is closed from the server before data upload is completed.

**Testing via `pycurl`**

Using the curl wrapper, I get a more interpretable response.

```py
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
b = BytesIO()

c.setopt(c.URL, service.scoring_uri)
c.setopt(c.POST, True)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER,['Content-Type: application/json'])
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, test_sample)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.perform()

out = b.getvalue()

b.close()
c.close()

print(out)
```

For large files, this yields the following error:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            413 Request Entity Too Large
        </title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>
                413 Request Entity Too Large
            </h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>
                nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Leading me to believe this is an issue in the Nginx configuration. Specifically, I guess that client_max_body_size is set to 10mb.

**Question summarised**

Given that I am indeed hitting an issue with the Nginx configuration, can I change it somehow? If not using the Azure Machine Learning Service SDK, then maybe by overwriting the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

In the built images, client_max_body_size in nginx configuration is set to 100m. Changing nginx configuration is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

For scoring large data, you might want to look into different architecture. Passing large amounts of raw data in HTTP request body is not the most efficient way.

For example, you can build a scoring pipeline. See this notebook for example: [Pipeline Style
   Transfer](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/pipeline-style-transfer/pipeline-style-transfer.ipynb)

Alternatively, if you want to use ACI web service, you could stage the images to a blob store, and then pass the images by reference to blob location.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs :)

In reality, I'm only testing the image on ACI before deploying to a Data Box Edge via IoT Hub. My colleagues and I, are still trying to figure out the optimal architecture here. It might indeed be passing references to files on disk rather than the files themselves.